# AngularJS : Factory $http assigning values returning null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I am trying to assign a variable from $http.get() though the conf var is null despite the request going through and returning json.

```
app.factory('Config', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        return {

            conf: null,

            init: function () {

                if (this.conf === null) {
                    $http.get('/config')
                        .success(function (data) {
                            this.conf = data;
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside `success callback function` is different

```
app.factory('Config', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        return {

            conf: null,

            init: function () {
                var self = this;
                if (this.conf === null) {
                    $http.get('/config')
                        .success(function (data) {
                            self.conf = data;
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I tried this previously, guess I must have had a typo, worked though cheers